# Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) but code executes properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that will basically copy and paste data from one sheet to another. The code executes and runs fine up until the last bit where I need to remove the last three characters from each cell in a specified column.

The code does this just fine, but I always get an error afterwards

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

This is the piece where Excel identifies the error even though it does its job by removing the last three characters of the cell value. Before the cell values are changed they look like 000123.HK

My code is supposed to remove the .HK at the end

Would appreciate any help on this, also happy to have tips on how to make my code more efficient!

```
With Worksheets("Earnings Final")
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        .Cells(i, "B") = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, Len(.Cells(i, "B").Value) - 3)
    Next i
End With
```

Full code below:

```
Private Sub button_Click()

Dim ricRange As Range
Dim ricEveryNth As Range
Dim ricRow As Long

Dim sRange As Range
Dim sEveryNth As Range
Dim sRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("SheetA").Activate

With Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set ricRange = .Range("A2", Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1").Cut
Worksheets("SheetA").Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

For ricRow = 1 To ricRange.Rows.Count Step 3
If ricRow = 1 Then
    Set ricEveryNth = ricRange(ricRow, 1)
Else
    Set ricEveryNth = Union(ricRange(ricRow, 1), ricEveryNth)
End If
Next ricRow
Application.Goto ricEveryNth

Selection.Copy
Sheets("SheetB").Activate
Worksheets("SheetB").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

With Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set sRange = .Range("B1", Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

For sRow = 1 To sRange.Rows.Count Step 3
If sRow = 1 Then
    Set sEveryNth = sRange(sRow, 1)
Else
    Set sEveryNth = Union(sRange(sRow, 1), sEveryNth)
End If
Next sRow
Application.Goto sEveryNth

Selection.Copy
Sheets("SheetB").Activate
Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

' Remove .HK from stock codes

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer


Sheets("SheetB").Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("SheetB")
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        .Cells(i, "B") = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, Len(.Cells(i, "B").Value) - 3)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are getting the last row of worksheet B, but then using it as a row for worksheet A - Which one are you trying to get? This will fail unless they both have the same number of rows.

Comment: Need last row of worksheet B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the Left/Len method probably failing. Check if len is greater than 3 because you might be getting Left(string, x) where x might be negative:

```
With Worksheets("Earnings Final")
  For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Len(.Cells(i, "B")) >= 3 Then
      .Cells(i, "B") = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, Len(.Cells(i, "B").Value) - 3)
    End If
  Next i
End With
```

Comment: That did the trick! Might be a formatting issue before and after the cells are pasted into the new sheet as all the cell values start with 0's. Thank you so much!